# GDB doesn't find sources

Tags: c, debugging, gcc, gdb

I start gdb using this (working dir is /home/leon/Develop/tests/atomic/):

```
 gdb ./bin/lin64/httpress
```

Then I add directories with source files, and it understands me:

```
Source directories searched: /home/leon/Develop/tests/atomic/third/http_parser:/home/leon/Develop/tests/atomic/src/tools:$cdir:$cwd
```

When I run my binary, gdb doesn't recognize the line in my source code, where segfault happened.
How to set source files for gdb?

The program is compiled by gcc:

```
gcc -D_AMD64_ -D_LIN_ -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_GNU_SOURCE -m64 -march=core2 -O2   -Wall -I. -I src/include -I src/lib/zlib/ -I src/lib/otg -I third/openssl/include/ -I src/lib/otg/Tools/HostTime/Interfaces/ -I src/lib/otg/Tools/OpenToolsGate/Guest/Interfaces/ -I src/lib/otg/Tools/OpenToolsGate/Guest/Cross -I src/lib/otg/Tools/OpenToolsGate/Common/Interfaces/ -o bin/lin64/httpress -std=c99  -lpthread -lev -lgnutls -O2 -s -DWITH_SSL -Wno-strict-aliasing \
        -I /usr/include/libev src/tools/httpress.c -I third/http_parser/ third/http_parser/http_parser.c
```

---

Ok, I've made some changes:

```
gcc -g -ggdb -D_AMD64_ -D_LIN_ -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_GNU_SOURCE -m64 -march=core2 -Wall -I. -I src/include -I src/lib/zlib/ -I src/lib/otg -I third/openssl/include/ -I src/lib/otg/Tools/HostTime/Interfaces/ -I src/lib/otg/Tools/OpenToolsGate/Guest/Interfaces/ -I src/lib/otg/Tools/OpenToolsGate/Guest/Cross -I src/lib/otg/Tools/OpenToolsGate/Common/Interfaces/ -o bin/lin64/httpress -std=c99  -lpthread -lev -lgnutls -s -DWITH_SSL -Wno-strict-aliasing \
        -I /usr/include/libev src/tools/httpress.c -I third/http_parser/ third/http_parser/http_parser.c
```

In this case it still can't find symbols in the binary.
But if I remove -s option from gcc call. It writes:

```
Reading symbols from /home/leon/Develop/tests/atomic/bin/lin64/httpress...done.
```

But the debugger still says this:

```
(gdb) info source
No current source file.
```

...after I point him directories with sources.

Comment: If you're not running the program, is normal that `info source` returns `No current source file`. Have you tried `info sources`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You miss the `-g` in your `gcc` call to include debugging information.

On the other hand, I suggest to decrease optimization level from `-O2` to `-O0` and use it only once (included `gcc` call has 2 `-O2`).

Apart of this, you can add directories to gdb's source path with `dir` command: [Source_Path](http://www.sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Source-Path.html). But this would only work if you've proper debug information available in `httpress`

Comment: It seems gdb already sees debugging symbols (with removing -s option), but it does not find sources.

Comment: @Leonidas Please, check my comment on question's update. Try `info sources` instead of `info source`

Answer (score 4):

> But the debugger still says this:
>
> (gdb) info source
>   No current source file.
>   ...after I point him directories with sources.

This is *expected*. There is no current source because you haven't started executing your binary yet.

You want to `start` or `run` your binary and get it to some place in execution (e.g. `main`, or the crash point).

Answer (score 3):

Remove optimize flag :

```
-O2
```

And add that flags:

```
-g -ggdb
```